# Is it possible to transfer data between html pages driven by spring web flow?

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-webflow

I am aware of passing data between `jsp` in spring web flow.

Is it possible to transfer data between html pages driven by spring web flow. I don't want to use the HTML5 local storage capabilities.

Example:

`Page 1:` Search box for an employee id.
`Page 2:` Search result for the employee details.

Two ways that I could think:

1. Get the employee details in *page 1* by ajax and pass the result to the *page two*.
2. Pass the employee id to *page 2* and get the result by ajax in `onload`.

In both case I need to pass any variable/data. I am confused in doing this.

Is there anything in the Spring webflow using which I could do this?

Thanks in advance,
Easwar

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can do either one.  You'll need to have a listener in between to accept the employee ID from page 1, do the search for details, put the results into request or session scope, and redirect to the displaying page.  You don't even need Spring web flow to do it; a simple Controller will do.

I don't even see why you'd need two pages.  It's common for the selection from one text box or drop down to be used to populate a second on the same page.

Comment: Thanks duffymo ! Actually my requirement is to use HTML(Not JSP) and Spring webflow. Is it still possible. If so, could you please explain how to set up the listener for the same. I am beginner in this.

Comment: Yes, the listener is a Spring controller mapped to a particular URL.  Make your AJAX call with the value from the first drop down part of the HTTP request.  The controller takes the value, gets the response, and adds it to the Model for the next page.  I didn't say JSPs anywhere; it works with straight HTML.

Comment: But... but... how do you get things off request or session scope in plain HTML? If you really need the source to be plain HTML, nothing dynamic at all, I don't know how you do this.